# Accessing son data Firebase

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase

I have a problem, I'm trying to access some data on firebase this is the data structure

[image: Firebase Tree]

I managed to access "favorite"
This is what I used to get

```
ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        let fav = snapshot.value.objectForKey("favPost")
        print("\(fav) Printed")
    })
```

but I'm trying to access "favPost" but I couldn't figure it out?!!

---

Firebase structure

```
{
  "posts" : {
"-KGIxJybfQEJbcSy2bHH" : {
  "author" : "Rioodi",
  "postText" : "Test",
  "votes" : 1
},
"-KGIxLUmPIa1Q1k0oRLs" : {
  "author" : "Rioodi",
  "postText" : "Raed",
  "votes" : 0
},
"-KGJe-5ciAyu6Kom98E0" : {
  "author" : "Neal",
  "postText" : "Neal",
  "votes" : 0
},
"-KGLFC0RqW_48lHMCsx8" : {
  "author" : "Rioodi",
  "postText" : "Test",
  "votes" : 0
}
  },
  "users" : {
"afd0f27a-f62f-4cf1-9e81-032edc246687" : {
  "email" : "test@test.com",
  "favorite" : {
    "-KGIxJybfQEJbcSy2bHH" : {
      "favPost" : "Test"
    }
  },
  "provider" : "password",
  "username" : "Rioodi"
},
"fc56cc22-6275-48e0-8376-0b73b273b8e2" : {
  "email" : "tests@test.com",
  "provider" : "password",
  "username" : "Neal"
}
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your Firebase structure as text! You can easily get that by using the Export button in the Firebase Dashboard.

Comment: okay I posted the firebase structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the userId and you also know you are looking for their favorite post, directly access it like this.

```
let usersRef = self.myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("users")
let thisUserRef = usersRef.childByAppendingPath("this users id")
let thisUserFavoriteRef = thisUserRef.childByAppendingPath("favorite")

thisUserFavoriteRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    let fav = snapshot.value["favPost"] as! String
    print(fav)

})
```

you could combine the path into a single line as well

```
let thisUserFavoriteRef = rootRef.childByAppendingPath("users/this users id/favorite")
```

Comment: I used what you said but (snapshot.key) printed "favorite" and (snapshot.value) printed "All the dictionary"  why?!

Comment: @Rioodi Holy cow, I am so sorry. I typo'd in my answer. The .Value event should have been .ChildAdded, and the print statements were incorrect. I've updated the answer to actually *work*. You should probably add code for the optional being nil... if let fav = snapshot.value["favPost"] as? String {} if there's a possibility that it would be nil.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code. (you can change according to requirements.)

```
 ref.observeEventType( .Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

           //lets consider you have reached up to "favarites"

      let favarites = snapshot?.value as! [ String : [ String : AnyObject ] ]

      //In "favarites" array you will get whole list  
      for favarite in favarites
      {
          let favPost = favarite.1[ "favPost" ] as? String  //to access value part
          print("\(favPost) Printed"
       }               
     }
```

Comment: the problem what if the value is Null the app will crash

Comment: Don't worry solved it By checking for NSNull first ^_^